# Which config ? tomcat nat or combo tomcat+mod_jk+apache

Tags: performance, java, apache-httpd

I just received my Raspberry pi which I plan to use for a gwt webapp.

In performance view, what will be better to do ?

- only tomcat with NAT to serve my http external port
- serving static content (.png) via symlinks in apache documentroot + mod_jk for mapping webapp + tomcat for serving dynamic stuff

Feel free to explain other way to do !

thanx in advance

Comment: One year later, I can say running tomcat with mod_jk is quite good for my website.
I must admit, my web app is not a big big stuff, and is not getting 500 simultaneous connections (neither 5 in fact).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Jetty over tomcat. If you can bundle Jetty with your app and launch it via java --jar you'll simplify it and can tweak it to run with the least memory possible.

I've used jetty with long running batch apps before. it's pretty easy to embed and allows you to have a live peek into a server or batch processing tool.